# How to get the boxes to lay on the page

Tags: html, css

I currently have http://twclaimer.com/twopcenter/internal/index.html and as you can see the Ad on the Right pushes all the content down. And if you look at the bottom of the page the boxes fit how I want them to.

How can I get the ad on the right to not push down all the content down?

Comment: I'm thinking I need to do add styles to box:after{ }, but I'm not sure what I need to add

Comment: can you set up the problem as a fiddle? http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: One of your problems is that there isn't actually enough space. But it's pushing the content down for a different reason.

Answer (score 0):

When using `float`, when elements need to go to a new line they clear down to the bottom of the tallest element from the previous line.

In other words, there's no way for you to have the boxes where you say you want them if you keep using `float`.

It's okay to use `float: right` for the ad box, but for the rest you may be better off using `display:inline-block` instead.

Comment: I tried inline-block. Seems to work a little better, but now the page is shifted down so it aligns with the bottom of the Ad box.

Comment: Did you put `float: right` on the ad box? Try adding `vertical-align:top`.